# Cannot import modules from parent folder

Tags: python, python-import

I've been fighting with this for weeks, read so many (outdated) articles, tried so many different proposed solutions without success. And I still believe I'm not trying to do something difficult...

I have the following folder structure

```
├── script.py 
├── lib 
│   ├── lonlatboxes.py
│   ├── utils.py
```

I'm using the folder `lib` to store some libraries used in `script.py`.

In `utils.py` I have

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # python package
from lonlatboxes import lonlatboxes # my module
```

In `lonlatboxes.py` I have

```py
lonlatboxes = {
    'Africa': [-26.0, 63.0, -41.0, 37.0],
}
```

In `script.py` I do

```py
import lib.utils
```

And this causes an error

```py
      1 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
----> 2 from lonlatboxes import lonlatboxes
      3 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lonlatboxes'
```

I guess because the `sys.path` is resolved w.r.t. the parent folder and not `lib`. Note that the `lib.utils` file is found!

How should I solve this? Or...am I doing something completely against Python imports?
I believe adding the path to `sys.path` should not be the correct solution.

Note that I DON'T want to create a package. I just have a set of scripts and small libraries and want to avoid to put everything into the same folder and instead keep them separated so that I can have more order :)

Comment: Try to add empty __init__.py to the lib folder

Comment: Maybe try `from lib.lonlatboxes import lonlatboxes` (in `utils.py`)? This seems to work for me. I think this line is called as it was in the `script.py` folder. I think using `lib.` won't borrow you, unless you want the user to directly open `utils.py`. In that case, you can detect it by typing the following in `utils.py`: `if __name__ == "__main__":from lonlatboxes import lonlatboxes else: from lib.lonlatboxes import lonlatboxes`

Comment: the __init__.py does not work. I don't know why it is suggested as solution on many articles, I believe it used to work in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change the second `import` in `utils.py` and make it relative to `script.py`'s location:

#### `utils.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # python package
from .lonlatboxes import lonlatboxes # my module
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I gave the relative import a try in the past but somehow they never worked out. That makes sense.

Comment: Guido: Indeed, many have problems with relative imports — see [Relative imports for the umpteenth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-umpteenth-time).

Answer (score -1):

try to add this to your script.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import lib.utils
```

then modify your utils.py import section to:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from .lonlatboxes import lonlatboxes
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to avoid :( Adding the path to `sys.path` from what I read should not be the preferred solution.